# Error LDAP en Node.js: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

Tags: nodejs, ldap

Tengo un servidor Node.js y estoy usando `"ldapjs": "^1.0.2"` para hacer una conexión contra un directorio activo:

```
var ldapClient = await ldap.createClient({url: config.ldap.host + ':' + config.ldap.port})
```

Y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
 Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN XXXXX
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26) {
    errno: -3001,
    code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'XXXXX'
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que desde el servidor donde despliegas la aplicación node.js se resuelve la DNS indicada en `config.ldap.host` (hostname: 'XXXXX')?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Dicho esto, ¿Podrías indicarnos si el nombre del host que has introducido es el nombre de un equipo privado de tu red local o de un equipo público en Internet? Si no nos pones en contexto no sabremos qué te está pasando solo con el mensaje de error de que no resuelve la DNS del host que has indicado.